# Find sAMAccountName of manager for a user using samaccountname of user as input in Bash

Tags: bash, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

How do we find the sAMAccountName of a users manager with samaccountname of the user as input ? I tried doing in 2 steps where first i'm trying to fetch the users manager details by using manager attribute but that only has the CN of manager in output and then passing the same as input to other ldapsearch query.
However this does not fetch any data ? Is there any other way i can get the sAMAccountName of users manager in bash using users samaccountname ?

Query 1:-

```
mgr_cn=`ldapsearch -H ldaps://vodaldaps-ala.voda.regn.net  -x  -w $pass  -D "voda\ramesh01"  -b "OU=User Accounts,DC=voda,DC=regn,DC=net" "(&(objectclass=user)(samaccountname=john01))" manager | grep manager: | cut -d',' -f1,2 | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\\' `

echo $mgr_cn
Lambert, Mark (VOD-MUM)
```

Query 2:-

```
ldapsearch -v -x -LLL -H ldaps://vodaldaps-ala.voda.regn.net:636 -D 'voda\ramesh01' -w $pass  -b "dc=voda,dc=regn,dc=net" "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=$mgr_cn))" sAMAccountName

No Output fetched.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your domain part of an AD forest and the manager is on a different domain? That would explain it, since the base DN you're giving it wouldn't be accurate.

Regardless, I think you can simplify this by using the full distinguished name that the `manager` attribute gives you, rather than trying to extract just the CN portion. Something like this:

```
mgr_dn=`ldapsearch -H ldaps://vodaldaps-ala.voda.regn.net  -x  -w $pass  -D "voda\ramesh01"  -b "OU=User Accounts,DC=voda,DC=regn,DC=net" "(&(objectclass=user)(samaccountname=john01))" manager | grep manager:

echo $mgr_dn

ldapsearch -v -x -LLL -H ldaps://vodaldaps-ala.voda.regn.net:636 -D 'voda\ramesh01' -w $pass  -b "$mgr_dn" -s base "(objectClass=*)" sAMAccountName
```

That last line sets the baseDN to the DN of the manager, and the search scope to `base` so that it can only return the object at the baseDN (the manager's account).

However, if the manager is on a different domain, that may still not work because you're connecting to port 636, which will only return values for the current domain. You can change that to port 3269, which is the port for the Global Catalog (with SSL), so it returns objects from the entire AD forest.

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel Luci for the reply. However, i still don't get the output and see below err msg:

filter: (objectclass=*)
requesting: sAMAccountName
No such object (32)   
Additional information: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100245, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0

Any advice ?

Comment: Does the DN of the manager look valid and on the same domain as the user?